# Wordpress (WP ecommerce) add publish/unpublish to row actions

Tags: php, wordpress

How can I add a publish/unpublish quick button in wordpress admin post grid (like Edit, Quick Edit, ... on the screenshot)

[image: ![wordpress row actions]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wwmj.png)

This is a screenshot from wp-ecommerce plugin product grid (it is very similar to wordpress native post grid).

For example the code for the duplicate button from wp-e-commerce plugin is:

```
function wpsc_action_row( $actions, $post ) {

if ( $post->post_type != "wpsc-product" )
        return $actions;

$url = admin_url( 'edit.php' );
$url = add_query_arg( array( 'wpsc_admin_action' => 'duplicate_product', 'product' => $post->ID ), $url );

    $actions['duplicate'] = '<a href="'.esc_url( $url ).'">' . esc_html_x( 'Duplicate', 'row-actions', 'wp-e-commerce' ) . '</a>';

    $publishUrl = 'edit.php?wpsc_admin_action=toggle_publish&product='.$post->ID;

    if($post->post_status == 'publish') {
            $published = 'Unpublish';
    } else {
            $published = 'Publish';
    }

    /* $actions['publish_toggle'] = '<a href="'.$publishUrl.'">' . esc_html_x( $published, 'row-actions', 'wp-e-commerce' ) . '</a>'; */
return $actions;
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_update_featured_product', 'wpsc_update_featured_products' );
add_action( 'admin_init'                     , 'wpsc_update_featured_products' );
```

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status_Transitions

Comment: [Maybe this can help](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/149143/hide-the-post-count-behind-post-views-remove-all-published-and-trashed-in-cus).